# The value handed over through dynamic routing does not return well

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement dynamic routing and want to hand over the value when card is clicked.
For this, I made json file and product list component and product detail page component.
To deliver data that fits each card, I used `useParams` and `filter` function to match parameter.

Each url of detail page is well divided but, data from json file for the page is not handed over.
I think the usage of `filter` function is wrong. So, I upload the entire code, but I think you can just check the `filter` function part of the code `Products.jsx`.
May I know how to modify it??

**data.json**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "shirts",
      "price": 193700,
      "checked": true,
      "amounte": 1,
      "img": "https://shopimg.kakaofriendsgolf.com/live/images/2022/8/23/18/551886_1661246483199.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "pants",
      "price": 128700,
      "checked": true,
      "amounte": 1,
      "img": "https://shopimg.kakaofriendsgolf.com/live/images/2022/8/22/18/18783_1661159105201.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "vest",
      "price": 167700,
      "checked": true,
      "amounte": 1,
      "img": "https://shopimg.kakaofriendsgolf.com/live/images/2022/9/7/10/918997_1662515279620.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Cards.jsx (this is list of products)**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import dummy from "../database/data.json";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Cards() {
  // json to state
  const [data, setData] = useState(dummy.products);

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div className="cardWrap">
        {data.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Link
              to={`/product/${item.id}`}
              style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "inherit" }}
            >
              <div key={item.id} className="card">
                <div className="card__imgWrap">
                  <img className="card__img" alt="product" src={item.img} />
                </div>
                <div className="card__nameWrap">
                  <div className="card__name">{item.name}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div`
  overflow: scroll;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;

  .cardWrap {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    top: calc(50vh - 100px);
    left: calc(50vw - 100px);
  }

  .card {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .card__imgWrap {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }

  .card__img {
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }

  .card__nameWrap {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .card__name {
    display: flex;
  }
`;
```

**Products.jsx (this is detail page of products. I guess filter function of this component is wrong)**

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import dummy from "../database/data.json";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Product() {
  // parameters for dynamic routing
  const params = useParams().id;

  // I think this part is wrong
  const productList = dummy.products.filter(
    (item) => item.params === Number(params)
  );

  console.log("productList :", productList);

  return (
    <Wrap>
      <div>
        {productList.name}
      </div>
    </Wrap>
  );
}

const Wrap = styled.div``;
```

I will also attach the codesandbox for easier understanding of the code.

> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-routing-xz4znr?file=/src/components/Cards.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're comparing the `id` with `params` in your filter in `Product` component, you should compare with the `id`.

Second thing, with the filter function you will get an array, it is better to use find :

```
const productList = dummy.products.find(
    (item) => item.id === Number(params)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const productList = dummy.products.find(
(item) => item.id === Number(params) // let productList recieve the item value when item.id = Number(params)
);
```

`item` is your object `product` it does not have any attribute `params`